# VS COde Not detecting Android device r emulator but showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Images are attached.
IN Android Studio 4 devices available 2 web 1 emulator and 1 real device
But in VS CODE only 2 web browser detected.
i am new to flutter need help.
Developer and usb debugging on.
[VS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKQ2k.png)

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6weYm.png)
[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hqqD.png)

Comment: 3 images are attached one for VS CODE and other 2 For ANDROID STUDIO

Comment: Reinstall flutter and dart extension and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first run the device either through vscode or android studio and then type flutter devices in cmd only then you will see your emulator as one of the options.
In vscode in the bottom right corner you can select your emulator by clicking on this option:

[image]